# inset box-shadow showing a border around and need to hide it

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

I created a div with css to make it circle, and I added inner box shadow

```css
.circle {
  width: 690px;
  height: 690px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 80px 50px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a small padding and adjust the [`background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip):

```css
.circle {
  width: 690px;
  height: 690px;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 80px 50px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  padding: 1px;
  background-clip: content-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

You can also recreate the same using `radial-gradient`:

```css
.circle {
  width: 690px;
  height: 690px;
  background: radial-gradient(#000 57%,transparent 70%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```